# ActionScript 3: Item added to scene, once hit, cannot be removed/found to remove

Tags: actionscript-3, target

I "think" what I am doing is correct, but it must not be. Imagine an object that floats in the middle of the scene, we can call it `gbl.obj`. Randomly other elements get added to the scene and if `gbl.obj` hits one, it's game over. Now after that I want to "reset" if you will. Reset consists of removing the elements that were added. I don't know the best way to reference these objects and I'm willing to bet that is my issue. I add them like so:

```
var bottom = randomRange(75,250);
var pipeTop:Shape = new Shape; // initializing the variable named rectangle
pipeTop.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000); // choosing the colour for the fill, here it is red
pipeTop.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 75,bottom); // (x spacing, y spacing, width, height)
pipeTop.graphics.endFill(); // not always needed but I like to put it in to end the fill
pipeTop.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, hitTarget);
pipeTop.name = 'pipe';
addChild(pipeTop);
var pipeBottom:Shape = new Shape; // initializing the variable named rectangle
pipeBottom.graphics.beginFill(0x00FF00); // choosing the colour for the fill, here it is red
pipeBottom.graphics.drawRect(0, bottom+125, 75,480-177-bottom); // (x spacing, y spacing, width, height)
pipeBottom.graphics.endFill(); // not always needed but I like to put it in to end the fill
pipeBottom.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, hitTarget);
pipeBottom.name = 'pipe';
addChild(pipeBottom);
var topPipe = new Tween(pipeTop, 'x', None.easeIn,400,pipeTop.x-1000,200,false);
var bottomPipe = new Tween(pipeBottom, 'x', None.easeIn,400,pipeBottom.x-1000,200,false);

function hitTarget(e:Event):void{
  if (gbl.obj.hitTestObject(pipeTop) == true || gbl.obj.hitTestObject(pipeBottom) == true) {
    topPipe.stop();
    bottomPipe.stop();
    pipeTop.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, hitTarget);
    pipeBottom.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, hitTarget);
    fail();
  }
}
```

Essentially these items move across the screen. When hit, I stop them can call a fail function that stops all animations essentially. Then when the reset button is pressed, this happens:

```
Object(this).Overlay.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_MouseClickHandler);
startGround();
gbl.obj.y = 200; 
gbl.timer = setInterval(doPipe,2300);
fall();
gbl.gameOver = false;
for(var i = 0; i < this.numChildren; i++){
  var item = this.getChildAt(i);
  if(item.name == 'pipe'){
    this.removeChildAt(i);
  }
}
```

Now what happens every time is all of these pipes get removed except for the one my object did not hit. When I try to just trace all of the objects that are children of the scene it's not there. When I remove any checking and just remove all of the children, it stays. Where is the element gone?

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way of cleaning up your stage is to place your temporary objects in their own container.  While your method of iterating over child elements should work, using a container for removables makes cleanup a one-stop command.

```
var bottom = randomRange(75,250);
var container:Sprite;
var pipeBottom:Shape, pipeTop:Shape;
var topPipe, bottomPipe;

function setup():void {
    container = new Sprite();
    addChild(container);

    pipeTop = new Shape; // initializing the variable named rectangle
    pipeTop.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000); // choosing the colour for the fill, here it is red
    pipeTop.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 75,bottom); // (x spacing, y spacing, width, height)
    pipeTop.graphics.endFill(); // not always needed but I like to put it in to end the fill
    pipeTop.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, hitTarget);
    pipeTop.name = 'pipe';
    container.addChild(pipeTop);

    pipeBottom = new Shape; // initializing the variable named rectangle
    pipeBottom.graphics.beginFill(0x00FF00); // choosing the colour for the fill, here it is red
    pipeBottom.graphics.drawRect(0, bottom+125, 75,480-177-bottom); // (x spacing, y spacing, width, height)
    pipeBottom.graphics.endFill(); // not always needed but I like to put it in to end the fill
    pipeBottom.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, hitTarget);
    pipeBottom.name = 'pipe';
    container.container.addChild(pipeBottom);

    topPipe = new Tween(pipeTop, 'x', None.easeIn,400,pipeTop.x-1000,200,false);
    bottomPipe = new Tween(pipeBottom, 'x', None.easeIn,400,pipeBottom.x-1000,200,false);
}

function hitTarget(e:Event):void{
    if (gbl.obj.hitTestObject(pipeTop) == true || gbl.obj.hitTestObject(pipeBottom) == true) {
        topPipe.stop();
        bottomPipe.stop();
        pipeTop.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, hitTarget);
        pipeBottom.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, hitTarget);
        fail();
    }
}

function reset():void {
    removeChild(container);
    setup();
}
```

Comment: Using your method, I couldn't have more than one topPipe/bottomPipe on the stage at a time correct? I guess I could pass in the container objects to the hitTarget function rather than look at the globals.

Comment: You could have as many "pipes" as you want.  Any instantiated object has a default uniquely identifiable name (ie, "instance355"), and from a practical standpoint, child elements are simply properties of a numerically indexed array (DisplayListContainer).  The example you shared only created 2 pipes.  If you want more, why not abstract that part, and use a loop to generate X number of pipes.